# Javascript onmouseenter & onmouseleave

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I want to a icon in my menu but if the link be hover icon will change to text. I tried this with js onmouseenter and onmouseleave methods. I changed icon but end of hover i can't rechange the text to icon. Thanks for everything from now.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a id="link" href="#" onmouseenter="onMouseEnter(this)" onmouseleave="onMouseLeave(this)">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-twitter" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M5.026 15c6.038 0 9.341-5.003 9.341-9.334 0-.14 0-.282-.006-.422A6.685 6.685 0 0 0 16 3.542a6.658 6.658 0 0 1-1.889.518 3.301 3.301 0 0 0 1.447-1.817 6.533 6.533 0 0 1-2.087.793A3.286 3.286 0 0 0 7.875 6.03a9.325 9.325 0 0 1-6.767-3.429 3.289 3.289 0 0 0 1.018 4.382A3.323 3.323 0 0 1 .64 6.575v.045a3.288 3.288 0 0 0 2.632 3.218 3.203 3.203 0 0 1-.865.115 3.23 3.23 0 0 1-.614-.057 3.283 3.283 0 0 0 3.067 2.277A6.588 6.588 0 0 1 .78 13.58a6.32 6.32 0 0 1-.78-.045A9.344 9.344 0 0 0 5.026 15z"/>
      </svg>
</a>

<script>
    function onMouseEnter(x) {
        document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = "twitter";
    }
    function onMouseLeave(x) {
        return 0;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The same the other way round?

Comment: yes, exactly i tried return but it doesn't working

Comment: Please Post the best not working attempt. Return 0; seems Not to be the best.

Comment: I know it doesn't working actually i ask this what can i put instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your script functions as follow:

```js
function onMouseEnter(x) {
        x.innerHTML = "twitter";
    }
    function onMouseLeave(x) {
        x.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-twitter" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M5.026 15c6.038 0 9.341-5.003 9.341-9.334 0-.14 0-.282-.006-.422A6.685 6.685 0 0 0 16 3.542a6.658 6.658 0 0 1-1.889.518 3.301 3.301 0 0 0 1.447-1.817 6.533 6.533 0 0 1-2.087.793A3.286 3.286 0 0 0 7.875 6.03a9.325 9.325 0 0 1-6.767-3.429 3.289 3.289 0 0 0 1.018 4.382A3.323 3.323 0 0 1 .64 6.575v.045a3.288 3.288 0 0 0 2.632 3.218 3.203 3.203 0 0 1-.865.115 3.23 3.23 0 0 1-.614-.057 3.283 3.283 0 0 0 3.067 2.277A6.588 6.588 0 0 1 .78 13.58a6.32 6.32 0 0 1-.78-.045A9.344 9.344 0 0 0 5.026 15z"/></svg>'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this with css display property:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a id="link" href="#" onmouseenter="onMouseEnter(this)" onmouseleave="onMouseLeave(this)">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-twitter" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M5.026 15c6.038 0 9.341-5.003 9.341-9.334 0-.14 0-.282-.006-.422A6.685 6.685 0 0 0 16 3.542a6.658 6.658 0 0 1-1.889.518 3.301 3.301 0 0 0 1.447-1.817 6.533 6.533 0 0 1-2.087.793A3.286 3.286 0 0 0 7.875 6.03a9.325 9.325 0 0 1-6.767-3.429 3.289 3.289 0 0 0 1.018 4.382A3.323 3.323 0 0 1 .64 6.575v.045a3.288 3.288 0 0 0 2.632 3.218 3.203 3.203 0 0 1-.865.115 3.23 3.23 0 0 1-.614-.057 3.283 3.283 0 0 0 3.067 2.277A6.588 6.588 0 0 1 .78 13.58a6.32 6.32 0 0 1-.78-.045A9.344 9.344 0 0 0 5.026 15z"/>
      </svg>
<p style="display:none">Twitter</p>
</a>

<script>
    let svg = document.querySelector("svg");
    let text =  document.querySelector("#link>p")
    function onMouseEnter(x) {
      svg.style.display="none";
     text.style.display="block";
    }
    function onMouseLeave(x) {
       svg.style.display="block";
     text.style.display="none";
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly the two icons depicyted in the folowing snippet are the same but the mechanism should work for any number of social media ( or other ) links assigned the same class. This could have been done by assigning/toggling a particular class to the svg instead of adding and then remove the style attribute. The Javascript `mouseover` handler uses the `data-label` attribute to display some alternative content temporarily.

```js
const d=document;
const q=(e,n=d)=>n.querySelector(e);
const qa=(e,n=d)=>n.querySelectorAll(e);



qa('.link').forEach(a=>{
  a.addEventListener('mouseover',function(e){
    q('svg',this).style.display='none';
    this.classList.add('socmedia')
  });
  a.addEventListener('mouseout',function(e){
    q('svg',this).removeAttribute('style');
    this.classList.remove('socmedia')
  });
});
```

```css
.link{
  margin:1rem;
  display:block;
}

.socmedia:after{
  content:attr(data-label);
  display:inline-block;
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a class="link" href="#" data-label='Twitter'>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-twitter" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M5.026 15c6.038 0 9.341-5.003 9.341-9.334 0-.14 0-.282-.006-.422A6.685 6.685 0 0 0 16 3.542a6.658 6.658 0 0 1-1.889.518 3.301 3.301 0 0 0 1.447-1.817 6.533 6.533 0 0 1-2.087.793A3.286 3.286 0 0 0 7.875 6.03a9.325 9.325 0 0 1-6.767-3.429 3.289 3.289 0 0 0 1.018 4.382A3.323 3.323 0 0 1 .64 6.575v.045a3.288 3.288 0 0 0 2.632 3.218 3.203 3.203 0 0 1-.865.115 3.23 3.23 0 0 1-.614-.057 3.283 3.283 0 0 0 3.067 2.277A6.588 6.588 0 0 1 .78 13.58a6.32 6.32 0 0 1-.78-.045A9.344 9.344 0 0 0 5.026 15z"/>
  </svg>
</a>


<a class="link" href="#" data-label='Farcebook'>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-twitter" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M5.026 15c6.038 0 9.341-5.003 9.341-9.334 0-.14 0-.282-.006-.422A6.685 6.685 0 0 0 16 3.542a6.658 6.658 0 0 1-1.889.518 3.301 3.301 0 0 0 1.447-1.817 6.533 6.533 0 0 1-2.087.793A3.286 3.286 0 0 0 7.875 6.03a9.325 9.325 0 0 1-6.767-3.429 3.289 3.289 0 0 0 1.018 4.382A3.323 3.323 0 0 1 .64 6.575v.045a3.288 3.288 0 0 0 2.632 3.218 3.203 3.203 0 0 1-.865.115 3.23 3.23 0 0 1-.614-.057 3.283 3.283 0 0 0 3.067 2.277A6.588 6.588 0 0 1 .78 13.58a6.32 6.32 0 0 1-.78-.045A9.344 9.344 0 0 0 5.026 15z"/>
  </svg>
</a>
```